# squid proxy - only pass through, can I disable caching?

Tags: squid

I have a bunch of users that should access the internet through squid.
 I don't want to cache anything.
 I just want to fetch the requested page as fast as possible and deliver it to the user.

So can I just disable the cache?
I don't want to serve the users from cache. But I don't know if the cache is needed for better/faster working.

To what should I configure the memory?
I have 6GB and it can use all if it helps to speed up things.
Any other things I should keep in mind or I should set in squid.conf in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Proxies deliver requests "as fast as possible" BECAUSE they cache.

but if you insist, setting your cache size to 0 will do the trick.

Comment: thanks. Can I help squid with special memory settings? I think it still needs to safe the current page in memory before it delivers it.

Comment: Memory is memory, not a whole lot you can do with that except get more of it. You can however tweak how the server caches data. Why not throw Squid into your production environment and monitor the memory and the cache info? You may find 6 gigs to be plenty. If not, you can quickly disable the caching features. Read up on this here..

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidMemory

Comment: Okay, so when I disabling the cache I can maybe disable other things, too? I just want to give the users the latest page (fetch it from the server). But caching DNS and such things are okay. Can I still do this with just set the cache size to 0 or will I disable this way other useful things, too?